# Can I use a 150w 12v 775 DC motor with an old 800w PC PSU?

Tags: power-supply, dc-motor, amperage

Is it possible to use a 150W 12V motor with a PC PSU?

I know that it means that motor will draw a current of 12.5A from the PSU. The PSU can supply 20Amps in total on the +12V rail. As soon as connect the motor to pc PSU it will short and trip the supply( overcorrect protection is triggered).
I know that PC PSU hasn't been designed for motors but is there anyway to make them work together?

Comment: PC pay? Overcharged? Do not comment? Sounds like you need an inrush protection. Have you tried a ~0.5 ohm resistor?

Comment: Hi, Andy. (1) What is an "old PC pay" mentioned in your title? (2) Have you got a link to the PSU datasheet? (3) Where is the photo of the PSU rating plate which would tell us the rated output current? (4) What do you mean "do not comment"? Comments are for seeking clarification on questions and this one needs some. Capital 'W' for watt and 'V' for volt.

Comment: Autocorrect PSU into pay. Fixed for op.

Comment: you can jump green and black (ground) to turn it on. I use the 12 as banch power supply since years (you can use two capacitors to filter the jitter noise). The yellow cables are 12V

Comment: With no load on the PS primary output (likely 3.3 or 5V), the 12V won't be well-regulated.

Comment: And if I put a load on 3.3 and 5v it will work?

Comment: It may most likely be so that PSU isn't designed to deliver 800w in only 12V and as @stark says it may very possible be so that there aren't separeted regulator loop for the 3.3V 5V and 12V.